# access hardware information in nodejs

Tags: node.js, hardware

I want to use nodejs to access hardware information, like processor ID, HDD Serial, Active LAN card's MAC address and some other information. 
By using a windows specific command I can get ProcessorID and HDD serial number. But this system will be running on different OSes so I need cross platform solutions to getting this info.

How can I get this info for all platforms?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This question is a bit old but it returned in my google search, so I'll share a lib that I found. I'm not sure it is good because I didn't really use it, but seems nice despite it still has no support for Windows platform:
https://github.com/sebhildebrandt/systeminformation

Comment: Just found your suggestion for this library  https://github.com/sebhildebrandt/systeminformation - it now has a pretty good windows support. Perhaps you might try it.

Comment: there are lots of enhancements need to be added on that systeminformation library.... i just check it out as well...

Answer (score 9):

The `os` built in module will provide most of what you require and be cross-platform compatible.

https://nodejs.org/api/os.html

Using this module you can determine what platform you are running on and get other information your require using platform specific commands.

Comment: oznu thanks for the reply. 
I am using os library. But I need more information like my Processor ID, HDD serial number. Currently can't get those from os library.